# Is it common practice to cut portion of Bootstrap file and copy it in custom css files?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen in the HTML code of many websites classes like `.col-sm-4` and couldn't find a bootstrap css file in the resources. Do they make their custom classes with the same names of Bootstrap or what are they doing at all? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your Bootstrap package here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
Most custom built sites just include Grid system and Responsive utilities. You might not see bootstrap.css simply because it's part of their combined and minified main CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to how common it is overall, but I have certainly stripped out Bootstrap files in the past, and used my own instead. Depending on how custom the styles are going to be, removing the Bootstrap CSS can reduce a lot of bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Few possible reasons:

1. Bootstrap is not the only framework that uses such naming convention (i.e. `.col-sm-*`). They may be using other CSS framework.
2. They are indeed cutting out parts of bootstrap or other framework. It is certainly possible and doable, but know what you're doing and do it with caution.
3. They are combining their CSS files into one single one. You may not see bootstrap.css file in list of resources, but the actual bootstrap.css has been merged with other css files into one. This is a good practice as users don't have to make multiple file requests.